# Saving on page change in pagination not working. Values are not Saved

Tags: angularjs, pagination, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have a Table which I can edit. But if I change the page with pagination the edited values are deleted. I tried already to call my save function when change pages but that is not working as well.
I have a Table like this:

```
...
<table>
...
<th>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!valueForm.$visible" ng-click="valueForm.$show()">
                  Edit
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <form editable-form name="valueForm" onaftersave="$ctrl.saveColumn('valueTranlate')" ng-show="valueForm.$visible">
              <button type="submit" ng-disabled="valueForm.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
                Save
              </button>
              <button type="button" ng-disabled="valueForm.$waiting" ng-click="valueForm.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
                Cancel
              </button>
            </form>
          </th>
...
<tr dir-paginate="v in my array>
...
</table>
  <dir-pagination-controls auto-hide="false" on-page-change="$ctrl.saveColumn()" boundary-links="true" max-size='7'></dir-pagination-controls>
...
my .js
saveColumn() {
        if (this.$scope.valueForm.$visible) {
          angular.forEach(this.langV, (value) => {
            this.$http.patch('/api/dict_values/' + value.v_id, {
              id: value.v_id,
              value: value.value2,
              user_id: this.currentUser()._id,
              key_id: value._id,
              lang_id: this.$scope.select2
            });
          });
          this.showLang(this.$scope.select1, this.$scope.select2);
        }
      }
```

So calling `saveColumn()` it iterates all fields on every page and saves the values, but not the edits of other pages because the are "removed". Tried with calling `save()` on change of the page but values are "deleted" faster than the `save()`.

So how can I achieve that I can Edit on every page and if I change the Page the Values are not forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a Factory which "remembers" all Edited Values.
I added to my Textarea a ng-change to trigger this Factory everytime something happend.

```
 <span editable-textarea="v.value2"  e-ng-change="$ctrl.remember(v,$data)" e-name="valueTranslate" e-form="valueForm" e-rows="3" e-cols="25" onbeforesave="$ctrl.checkName($data)">
              {{v.value2 || '' }}
            </span>
```

First calling a `remember(v,$data)` function

```
      // Remember Edits for Pagination
    remember(obj, data) { //obj-> actual edited, data -> the input

        if (obj.close === undefined || obj.close === '' || obj.close === null) {
          obj.close = obj.value2;
        }// Attaching a Close property for the Case the User cancel the Edits

        obj.value2 = data;// saving the Edits in value2, this is which is get send to DB

        this.rememberValues.addValue(obj); // and send to Factory
      }
```

Then saving it in my Factory so the Edits wont be erased by ChangePange

```
.factory('rememberValues', () => {
  var valuesE = [];
  var savingValue;
  return {
    values: () => {
      return [].concat(valuesE);//for output and saving,contains all edited fields
    },
    addValue: (obj) => {//adding in Array
      savingValue = _.find(valuesE, function(value) {
        return value._id === obj._id;
      });
      if (savingValue) {
        savingValue.value2 = obj.value2;
      } else {
        valuesE.push(obj);
      }
    },
    clear: () => {//if I want to clear the Array
      angular.forEach(valuesE, (value) => {
        delete value.close;
      });
      valuesE = [];
    },
    cancel: () => {// The User Cancels the Edits
      angular.forEach(valuesE, (value) => {
        value.value2 = value.close;// Original Value is put in again
        delete value.close;
      });
      valuesE = [];
    }
  };
})
```